# Difference between IDictionary and IEnumerable<KeyValuePair>

Tags: c#, resharper

Resharper is suggesting that I change `IDictionary<string, string>` in the following line of code:

```
private static void createCookie(HttpCookie cookie, IDictionary<string, string> values)
```

to `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`.

I don't understand the advantage to using `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` over `IDictionary`.

Comment: Resharper is suggesting it to you because `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` is less restrictive than `IDictionary<string, string>` since you are not using any `IDictionary<,>`'s specific method in `createCookie`. It's only a suggestion.

Comment: @SimonBelanger +1 for "it's only a suggestion"

Comment: @blfemi3 you may very well find that the suggestion will go away after you implement the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Resharper noticed that you are not doing anything dictionary-specific in your code, so it suggest to allow more generic objects to be accepted as well. All you are doing in your code, you can also do with an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much advantage in this specific case.

However, in general, it's better to use the most general parameter type that you can, since it increases the number of ways that you can call the method.

So for your function, you could pass *anything* that implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`, which includes `IDictionary<string, string>` plus potentially many other types too.

Resharper doesn't know whether or not it would actually be that useful, so it always warns you about it.

Answer (score 1):

Resharper suggests to use base class/interface for method argument whenever it's possible.

It's related to Dependency inversion principle of OOP: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle.

Theoretically it's possible that there are some classes that implement IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> but don't implement IDictionary<string, string>.
And if you use IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> your method will be more universal because it will be able to work with larger set of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Resharper might wrong.  You are not using any of IDictionary's specific members now, but you might eventually add them in the future.  If this method should always work on dictionaries, then you might be better off defining that in your public interface.  That way if you end up changing the implementation in the future to use dictionary specific methods you won't be causing any problems.  Resharper only sees what you have written now, not what you expect to write in the future.

Comment: Whenever possible you want your methods to return immutable collections anyway.